# Group by pandas dataframe and impute missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a new calculated pandas column, however, I'd like to exclude certain rows, and calculate the value for the new column. And then to fill the values for excluded rows, I'd like to subset the dataframe by `df1.groupby['City']` and calculate the mean value to apply back to `new col` in original dataframe.

```
   df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                        'City': ['SF','NYC','SF','NYC','SF','CHI','LA','LA','CHI'], 
                        'Val': [2,4,0,0,7,4,3,5,6],
                        'Val1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
                       })

 
   df1['new col'] = np.nan

   for name, group in df.groupby(['City']):

       # Create Boolean Index
       m = group['Val'] != 0

       # Calculate rev_per_unit from grouped dataframe `group`
       stat = group.loc[m, 'Val'] / group.loc[m, 'Val1']


       # Assign stat to `df` at index locations where `Val` is 0 in group
       df.loc[group[~m].index, ''] = group['new col'].mean()
```

Expected output:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                        'City': ['SF','NYC','SF','NYC','SF','CHI','LA','LA','CHI'], 
                        'Val': [2,4,0,0,7,4,3,5,6],
                        'Val1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                        'new_col: [2,4,4.5,2,7,4,3,5,6]
                       })
```

The new column is a calculated column of `df1['Val] / df1['Val1']` excluding the `df['Val'] == 0` and then I impute the `new_col` for rows where `df['Val'] == 0` as grouped means.

Comment: What is the expected output? Did you mean `df.loc[group[~m].index, ''] = stat.mean()`?

Comment: the `new_col` would be the mean of the group, calculated excl. 0s in `df['Val']`. @HenryEcker updated the question with expected output.

Comment: Basically, the missing values are mean of values in `new_col` for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set `new_col` to `Val/Val1`:

```py
df1['new_col'] = df1['Val'] / df1['Val1']
```

Then use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) to compute the grouped means (set 0 to `nan` to ignore those rows):

```py
means = df1['new_col'].replace(0, np.nan).groupby(df1['City']).transform('mean')

# [4.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0]
# Length: 9, dtype: float64
```

Lastly impute the 0 locations with the grouped means:

- Either use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

  ```
  df1.loc[df1['Val'].eq(0), 'new_col'] = means
  ```
- Or [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

  ```py
  df1['new_col'] = df1['new_col'].mask(df1['Val'].eq(0), means)
  ```
- Or [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

  ```py
  df1['new_col'] = df1['new_col'].replace(0, np.nan).fillna(means)
  ```

So altogether:

```py
df1['new_col'] = df1['Val'] / df1['Val1']
means = df1['new_col'].replace(0, np.nan).groupby(df1['City']).transform('mean')
df1.loc[df1['Val'].eq(0), 'new_col'] = means

#   City  Val  Val1  new_col
# 0   SF    2     1      2.0
# 1  NYC    4     1      4.0
# 2   SF    0     1      4.5
# 3  NYC    0     1      4.0
# 4   SF    7     1      7.0
# 5  CHI    4     1      4.0
# 6   LA    3     1      3.0
# 7   LA    5     1      5.0
# 8  CHI    6     1      6.0
```

Comment: Not sure if the expected output has some typos or if I've misunderstood the question. For example I can't figure out why the expected `SF` outputs would be 2, 3, and 4. The first and last `SF` values are non-zero (2 and 7), so I'd expect their original values to be retained. The middle SF value is zero, so I'd expected that to be `mean([2,7])` which is 4.5, so the final `SF` output would be 2, 4.5, and 7. That's the logic behind the `transform`+`mask`.

Comment: The new column is a calculated column of `df1['Val] / df1['Val1']` excluding the `df['Val'] == 0` and then I impute the `new_col` for rows where `df['Val'] == 0` as grouped means. @tdy

Comment: But I'm still not seeing where the expected values come from. Like why is the 3rd `SF` output equal to 4? In that row, `Val`/`Val1` = 7/1 = 7, so there shouldn't be any imputation, but the expected `df` shows 4.

Comment: that was a typo. Imputed values for `new_col` are grouped means.